# Write on file of another server

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a file called `Sitemap.xml` on `Server1` and I want to write to this file from another server `Server2`.

File Structure of `Server1`

Server1:

- app
- views
- public
- sitemap.xml
- app.js

`Sitemap` can be accessed by `Server1/sitemap` as I have used below code in my express file

```
app.use('/sitemap', express.static(__dirname + '/sitemap.xml'));
```

Comment: Can you imagine if you could do it that simply? That would mean anyone could modify your files remotely!
What you need to do is create an API on server 1, something like /changeSitemap and have server2 call it

Comment: Actually, I don't want to expose my backend API that why I am trying to modify file from Server2 on Server1

Comment: Well that'd be even worse if you could do it that way haha
And you can always check whether the call comes from Server2 or not!

Answer (score 0):

You should to protect route with secret token to avoid exposing. Hope this will help you:

```
// Server 1
const fs = require('fs');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var secret = req.headers.hasOwnProperty('authorization')
    ? req.headers.authorization
    : false;

  if (! secret || secret !== 'token [your-secret-token]') {
    res.status(403).send('Access forbidden');
  }

  // Create write stream to sitemap file
  var stream = fs.createWriteStream('sitemap.xml');

  // Redirect request body to stream which writes to sitemap file
  req.pipe(stream)
  .on('end', () => res.send('ok'));
});


// Server 2

const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

var stream = fs.createReadStream('new-sitemap.xml');

var req = http.request({
  host: 'server1',
  headers: {
    authorization: 'token [your-secret-token]',
  },
});

req.on('response', (res) => {
  if (res.status === 200) {
    console.log('File uploaded');
  }
  else {
    console.error('File not loaded');
  }
});

// Write data from file into request body
stream.pipe(req);
```

Note that token should be minimum 32 chars length to be strong enough. And don't forget to update it from time to time. And also it's a concept.